# Git production and development server workflow

Tags: git, workflow

I am not sure whether the git workflow I intend to create between my production and development server is the right way of doing it.

This is what i have in mind: Development takes place on local computers and commits are `git push` to development server. Once a stable release is available, the production server does a `git pull` from development server. Any unexpected results on production can be reverted with `git revert`

Is it the correct way of doing this? If so, how do I make existing code sitting on the development server, a remote repo? Presumably, it's remote to both production and local as they `pull` and `push`.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it the correct way of doing this?

Yes, that sounds completely reasonable.

> If so, how do I make existing
>   code sitting on the development server, a remote repo? Presumably,
>   it's remote to both production and local as they pull and push.

Say you normally access your repo through ssh, like this:

```
brian@local$ ssh brian@development
brian@development$ cd /home/brian/code
brian@development$ git status
```

Then you can clone this code with `git clone ssh://brian@development:/home/brian/code`. You should be able to `git push` and `git pull` to and from development from then on.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it the correct way of doing this? If so, how do I make existing code sitting on the development server, a remote repo? Presumably, it's remote to both production and local as they `pull` and `push`.

Git is just a tool, there isn't any *corrent way* **or** how you use it makes it *the correct way*.

For your situation:

- There are 3 server ( or says 3 git repo )
- Local --push-to--> Development
- Production <--pull-from-- Development

So you can build Development git repo first, then clone to Production and Local:

```
user@development $ setup_git_repo.sh
user@local $ git clone ssh://user@development:/path/to/git/repo
user@production $ git clone ssh://user@development:/path/to/git/repo
```

Or you may clone via http:

```
user@development $ setup_git_repo.sh
user@local $ git clone http://development.server/git/repo
user@production $ git clone http://production.server/git/repo
```

Then you have 3 git repo. Local git repo and production git repo are cloned from development git repo.

Finally, you may do daily coding in local and push to development.
Do some test on development and release with new tag.
Run `git pull` on production server to get the latest code.

Comment: Isn't the order of where you init a repository and where you clone it unimportant? You could `git init --bare` a repository on some server, and then clone it on production, staging and local server. Or am I misunderstanding your concepts? I think you mean a staging system/server with "development"?